# R ggplot order legend geom_smooth and geom_abline

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I've found lots of other posts explaining how to change the order of legend produced by ggplot2 manually, and I've tried all the suggestions and still couldn't figure out the answer...

In my plot I'm showing a linear regression line from `geom_smooth` (with `lm` function) and another line that I fit arbitrarily using `geom_abline`.

```
ggplot(women, aes(x=height, y=weight)) +
  geom_point(size=3, shape = 21, color="black") +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", aes(color= "fit2", linetype = "fit2"), lwd=1, se = FALSE, show.legend = F) + 
  geom_abline(aes(intercept = -100, slope = 3.5, color="fit1", linetype = "fit1")) +
  scale_colour_manual(name="Legend", values = c("fit1" = "blue", "fit2" = "red")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name="Legend", values = c("fit1" = "solid", "fit2" = "dashed"))
```

This automatically makes a legend with "fit1" and "fit2", but I want "fit2" to show above "fit1". Lots of posts suggested reordering data in my dataframe, like `d$a <- factor(d$a, levels = d$a)`, but since my `geom_abline` is an arbitrary line I can't do that. I've tried `scale_fill_discrete(breaks=c("fit2","fit1"))` and `guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))` but both didn't work. Is there any other way to force "fit2" to show above "fit1"?

Comment: Unrelated, but I think those values for slope & intercept are outside the limits of the graph. Try `coef(lm(weight ~ height, data = women))` to get the correct values.

Comment: @neilfws Oh you're right, I changed the values of slope and intercept so that fit1 line actually shows up in the plot. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ggplot2` works best when you map variables (that is, column names) to geoms (lines, points *etc.* and their associated properties - colour, size), using `aes()`. When data is *tidy* you get things like legends "for free". It's generally not a good sign to see quoted words for variables inside of `aes()`.

Therefore I'd approach this task differently as follows:

1. use `lm()` for the linear regression
2. use `broom::augment` to create a data frame from the `lm` output
3. use `dplyr::mutate` to create a new column for `fit1`
4. `tidyr::gather` the data into a tidy data frame
5. convert `fit1`, `fit2` to factors which you can reorder
6. map the `geom_line` colour to `fit1`, `fit2`

   ```
   library(tidyverse)
   library(broom)

   women %>% 
     lm(weight ~ height, data = .) %>% 
     augment() %>% 
     mutate(fit1 = 3.5 * height - 100) %>% 
     select(weight, height, fit2 = .fitted, fit1) %>% 
     gather(fit, value, -weight, -height) %>% 
     mutate(fit = factor(fit, levels = c("fit2", "fit1"))) %>%
     ggplot() + 
       geom_point(aes(height, weight)) + 
       geom_line(aes(height, value, color = fit))
   ```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed!